# How to wait for input field to refresh in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In my AUT there are two fields - a `'Product'` drop down and an `'Amount'` input field. By default, the `'Amount'` field shows the value `'0.0'`. When user select a product from the `'Product'` drop down the `'Amount'` field gets auto populated with the price of the selected product if the price is already available in DB, otherwise the `'Amount'` field shows `'0.0'`. It takes a while to load the amount to `'Amount'` field after a product is selected. I cant observe any change in attribute value of the `'Amount'` field before and after it is auto populated. The html of the `'Amount'` field is

```
<input id="id_expense_amt" class="form-control input" name="expense_amt" step="0.01" value="0" type="number">
```

The question is that how can I make the webdriver to wait for the amount field to refresh after a product is selected. I used `Thread.sleep()` and it works fine. But is there any other method available.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two ways to achieve this scenario using `WebDriverWait` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

- If you already know what amount would be change in the `Amount` text field from default amount after selecting an option from `Product` dropdown, then you should try using [`ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElementValue-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.String-) which would wait until given amount is present in the specified elements value attribute as below :-

  ```
  webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(By.id("id_expense_amt"), "Amount which would be change"));
  ```
- If you don't know what amount would be change in the `Amount` text field from default amount after selecting an option from `Product` dropdown, but you know about default amount which is `0`, then you need to create custom `ExpectedConditions` which would wait until amount is change from default `0` to any new amount as below :-

  ```
  wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
              public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
               WebElement el = d.findElement(By.id("id_expense_amt"));
               String value = el.getAttribute('value');
               if(value.length() != 0 && !value.equals("0")) {
                  return true;
               }
            }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use the below one,you can change the timeunit based on your need.

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You can use this one as well

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 10);

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

Comment: Visibility of Amount field does not change. It is always visible

Comment: Then try to get the value of the drop down first index.If that is not visible then you can do the check again and again until you get the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact value that should be populated in the amount text box ,then you can use `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInEl‌ement`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); 
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInEl‌ement(By.xpath("text‌​box xpath"), "text for which you are waiting"));
```